# Question disappeared

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Just now I've been dealing with a newbie who had some Python problems. I gave him an answer which he found useful and which he accepted. So, I earned reputation. But in a few seconds that question disappeared! SO says it can't find such a question. Well, the reputation I earned from my answer has gone. My efforts too. What happened?

Comment: The error message when you see when visiting the question will tell you if it was deleted by the author or the community.

Comment: @Servy, I know, but how is it possible to delete a question that has an accepted answer??

Comment: For the author, he could have unaccepted it and then deleted it, for anyone else, it's no different than if there isn't an accepted answer.

Comment: If you post the link here from your browser history, users with more than 10k reputation can have a look at it.

Comment: This isn't possible if an answer to the question has one or more upvotes. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28284824/19679). It was deleted by the asker after you posted your answer.

Your answer wasn't accepted, nor did it have any upvotes on it, so you did not gain any reputation from it, nor did you lose any when it was deleted.

Given that this question was being downvoted and was pulling in close votes, I'm going to let it stay deleted.

Comment: Actually it ***was*** accepted, then unaccepted. So yes there would be reputation loss in the way of an unaccept. Basically seems like the user got their answer and decided to remove their question afterwards.

Comment: That's bad behavior on the part of the OP.

Comment: inb4 'Why am I question-banned?'